# PHP Image Matrix Maps

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a "form" where I place an image on the background and put multiple "buttons" and when I click that button I set a field to be to that area. Here is an image as an example:

[Image Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mY36.png)

And I would like those selections to be into a php variable. If I select B1 and B2 I would like the variable to be

```
var = "B1,B2"
```

Is there any framework to do this, or, what's the best way to code this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Mmm, 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp
Is what you need then on the click put it into a hidden variable.